# How to combine two has_many associations into one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

This seems to be a fairly common problem over here, yet there is no definitive solution. To restate once again, say I have a model:

```ruby
def Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :somethings, ...
    has_many :otherthings, ...
end
```

The question is then how to add a third association `:combined` that combines the two? I know this can be done with `:finder_sql` and similar result can be achieved with a `scope`, but neither of these gives me an actual association. The whole point of this is to be able to use it for another association with `:through` and things like `Model.first.combined.some_scope.count`

**EDIT: the relevant portions of the actual code**

```ruby
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
    # either Project or Nonprofit       
    belongs_to :donatable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :account
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :nonprofit
end

class Nonprofit < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects

    # donations can be either direct or through a project
    # the next two associations work fine on their own

    # has_many :donations, :as => :donatable, :through => :projects
    # has_many :donations, :as => :donatable

    has_many :donations, ....                       # how do I get both here,
    has_many :supporters, :through => :donations    # for this to work?
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `Something` and `Otherthing` are sufficiently similar, use STI:

```
def Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :somethings
  has_many :otherthings
  has_many :genericthings
end

def Genericthing < Activerecord::Base
  # put a string column named "type" in the table
  belongs_to :model
end

def Something < Genericthing
end

def Otherthing < Genericthing
end
```

Comment: They are the same thing, already using STI, but one of them comes `:through` a different model. In that custom `:finder_sql` I'd use LEFT JOIN and an OR clause.

Comment: Please be more explicit, add your intermediate models to the original question so everyone can get an idea on which problem to solve.